# Raknet build error

Tags: ios, xcode6, raknet

trying to build `[Raknet][1]` iOS with xCode 6.2

but I am getting error like

> /RakNet-master/Source/ReplicaManager3.cpp:141:61: Comparison between
>   pointer and integer ('RakNet::Connection_RM3 *' and 'int')

do anybody had successfully build RakNet on Xcode 6.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems C++ 11 issue, I get resolved with changing `false` to `nullptr`

earlier

```
if (GetConnectionByGUID(participantListIn[index], worldId)==false)
```

now

```
if (GetConnectionByGUID(participantListIn[index], worldId)==nullptr)
```